# Any standard String in SWIFT similar to UIColor.systemgray

Tags: ios, swift, string

In Android, we can access some standard string resources provided by the platform, e.g. `cancel`, `OK`, `delete` etc. It is convenient since I don't have to store all the translation for those simple texts.

I know that Swift provides something similar to UIColor, e.g. UIColor.systemgray.

My question is: Is there something similar but for `String`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically load localized strings from Apple's own frameworks. For instance, to load from `UIKit`, you'd use

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: UIView.self)
let string = bundle.localizedString(forKey: "Cancel", value: nil, table: nil)
```

When the current locale is German, this gives `"Abbrechen"`.

The downside of this approach is that you'll only know whether or not a specific string exists in the framework at runtime.

The best workaround I can think of for this is to define the keys that you use yourself and continuously verify them with a unit test.

For example you could gather all your system-string keys in a case-iterable enumeration

```
public enum SystemStringKey: String, CaseIterable {
    case cancel = "Cancel"
    ...
}
```

and use them to load the system strings via an extension on `String`

```
public extension String {
    static var systemStringBundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(for: UIView.self)
    }

    static func systemString(for key: SystemStringKey) -> String {
        return systemStringBundle.localizedString(forKey: key.rawValue, value: nil, table: nil)
    }
}
```

In code you can then use the system strings like constants

```
label.text = .systemString(for: .cancel)
```

To verify their continued existence, you could use a unit test such as this

```
class SystemStringKeyTests: XCTestCase {

    func testAllKeysExist() throws {
        let path = try XCTUnwrap(String.systemStringBundle.path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings"))
        let dict = try XCTUnwrap(NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path))
        for key in SystemStringKey.allCases {
            XCTAssertNotNil(dict[key.rawValue])
        }
    }

}
```

This isn't 100% bulletproof as it could still happen that Apple removes a string in an iOS update and then any released app that relied on that string would show the untranslated English string until you ship an update yourself.

---

**Update:** I threw together a Swift package for conveniently exploring and accessing available strings from system bundles. There are some caveats though. See https://nosuchdomain.mooo.com/git/doc/swift-systemstrings for further info.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no such static properties in Swift